# Please help me in instaliling adt 23

Tags: android, adt

I have the last version of eclipse but when I try to download the adt by using the installation method in help=>Install new software, it showed me the error and I don't know what to do please help me this is the error message

> "An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>       session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>       Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar.
>       SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>       Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar.
>       SSL peer shut down incorrectly"

Comment: Hi  instead of  using https once test with http sometimes work

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't officially support Oracle's JDK SE 7, it only supports Oracle's JDK SE 6 (although Java 7 does work with Android to an extent, it will give you all kinds of problems). Be sure to click on "Previous Versions" when reaching the Java Oracle web site.

[source](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Also, I assume you meant to say you're on Eclipse "Kepler" already.

Unfortunately, running the latest Eclipse is not always a good idea (even if they do say "Helios and above" are supported by ADT). The Android team is usually one release behind Eclipse, so it doesn't pay to be an early adopter in that case.